# Character-by-character chat client?

Tags: windows, software-rec, chat

I read about the [`talk`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/talk) command on linux, and how it lets you chat character-by-character rather then line-by-line like most chat clients or IRC.

Does anybody know where I might find a webapp or a chat client (that runs in Windows) that lets you chat in such a manner over the internet?

I did find a few related posts on some other forum ([metafilter](http://ask.metafilter.com/63098/Character-at-a-time-chatting), specifically), but nobody seemed to have a solution there. I also found a project on Google code ([TalkLively](http://code.google.com/p/talklively/)), but it looks like it requires a server and some setup to get working, which I'm not willing to do.

Comment: to whom do you want to chat in this manner? one other person at another machine? a group?

Comment: I suppose with one person at another machine.

Comment: do you need to go through firewalls? no setup required?

Comment: @akira: I'd like a solution that has a fairly good chance of working on most computer setups. I realize that stuff like firewalls can make some solutions difficult to implement, which is why I was hoping that I could find some webapp or program to circumvent issues like that altogether (although I'm willing to try and work around that if need be). I don't care how long it takes to set it up, as long as it isn't ridiculously onerous -- I really don't have many constraints or requirements :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AIM](http://www.aim.com/) can do this using a feature called Real-Time.

For more information, see [here](http://help.aol.com/help/microsites/microsite.do?cmd=displayKC&externalId=223568#faq3).

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a character-by-character chat web app called Textric, which you might want to try out (https://textric.com)